# VBA Change background colour of all cells affected by function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a function in VBA to loop through a range of cells and add them up until the total value is equal to a set maximum, what I would like to be able to do is set the background colour of all cells which are used in the SUM.

For example:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  , 5, =SumToValue(A1:E1, G1)
```

This will return 3 as 1 + 2 = 3, 3 + 3 = 6 which is above the maximum of 5.

Here is the code:

```
Function SumToValue(area As range, max As range)
    Application.Volatile

    Dim total As Long

    total = 0

    For Each cell In area
        If (WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell, total) <= max) Then
            total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell, total)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    SumToValue = total
End Function
```

So I need to set the background colour of A1 and B1 as they were calculated. However if I try adding `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 50` inside the loop then I get a `Value` error from the formula.

Is there anyway to do this or can functions not be used in this way?

Comment: Try declaring `cell` as `Range` (i.e. **Dim cell As Range**). You can then use: `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 50`. Also, **Option Explicit** is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your function as UDF (*User Defined Function*). In an UDF, it is not allowed to modify anything in your sheet, see for example https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

The best bet I can think about is to add a conditional rule using a formula to the cells. In your example, go to cell A1 and define the rule using the formula:

```
=SUM($A1:A1) <= $A$7
```

and enter `=A1:A5` for "Applies to".

Comment: Thank you, I am going to mark this as correct as I was looking into conditional formatting as a possible alternative.